# Array *not throwing out of bounds exception

Tags: java

I'm trying to learn about exception handling. I can't seem to get
String[] a = names(scnr); To throw an out of bounds exception when it goes beyond 3 elements. I know, most people hate the out of bounds error and I'm trying to make it happen and for the life of me I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. Been at it all day and googled all kinds of stuff. But I cannot seem to find exactly what I'm looking for. So I could use some help and perspective.

So I'm inputting a full string that I'm delimiting (trim and splitting) based on commas and spaces and then the pieces are being stored into an array (String []name), then passed to main to be output with String[] a. So it's not erroring when I go beyond 3 elements no matter how I do it. I can just not display anything beyond a[4]. But that's not really what I'm trying to do. Its my first java class so be gentle haha.

Any suggestions?

```
 import java.util.*;

public class ReturnArrayExample1  
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {  
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] a = names(scnr);           
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
        {
            System.out.println(a[i] + " in index[" + i + "].");
        }
        scnr.close();
    }  

    public static String[] names(Scanner scnr)  
    {                           
        String[] name = new String[3];      // initializing
        boolean run = true;
    do 
    {
        try
        {
        System.out.println("Enter 3 names separated by commas ',':(Example: keith, mark, mike)");
        String rawData = scnr.nextLine();
            if(rawData.isEmpty())
            {
                System.err.println("Nothing was entered!");
                throw new Exception();
            }
            else
            {
                name = rawData.trim().split("[\\s,]+");
                run = false;
            }
        }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Input is out of bounds!\nUnsuccessful!");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("Invalid entry!\nUnsuccessful!");
        }
    }
    while(run == true);
    
    System.out.println("Successful!");
    scnr.close();
    return name;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: `name = rawData.trim().split("[\\s,]+")` assigns a new array to the `name` variable. The original array of length 3 that was referenced by that variable becomes irrelevant. The new array may be shorter or longer than 3.

Comment: So how do I correct this?

Comment: @Eran Thats what I'm trying to figure out. I basically want to be able to split / trim the current array and throw an error if it goes beyond 3 indexes for the array. I just do not know how I go about affecting this in my code.

Comment: So check if `name.length > 3` and throw an exception

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to throw an ArrayOutOfBoundsException if the `names` array does not contain *exactly* 3 elements. The following code is the same as the one you wrote with an if-statement to do just that.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ReturnArrayExample1  
{  
   public static void main(String args[])
   {  
       Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
       String[] a = names(scnr);           
       for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
       {
           System.out.println(a[i] + " in index[" + i + "].");
       }
       scnr.close();
   }  

   public static String[] names(Scanner scnr)  
   {                           
       String[] name = new String[3];      // initializing
       boolean run = true;
   do 
   {
       try
       {
       System.out.println("Enter 3 names separated by commas ',':(Example: keith, mark, mike)");
       String rawData = scnr.nextLine();
           if(rawData.isEmpty())
           {
               System.err.println("Nothing was entered!");
               throw new Exception();
           }
           else
           {
               name = rawData.trim().split("[\\s,]+");
               if (name.length != 3) {
                   throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
               }
               run = false;
           }
       }
       catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
       {
           System.err.println("Input is out of bounds!\nUnsuccessful!");
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           System.err.println("Invalid entry!\nUnsuccessful!");
       }
   }
   while(run == true);
   
   System.out.println("Successful!");
   scnr.close();
   return name;  
   }  
}
```

Comment: I see that now. it still does not error though. @Eran above, mentioned this portion                                 
   name = rawData.trim().split("[\\s,]+")                      assigns a new array to the name variable..

Comment: It errs for me, if I tried just inputting "keith, mark"

Comment: hmm... so it's working with 3+ names, but not below. I clearly did something wrong. Just not sure what I did or how to fix it.

Comment: `OutOfBoundsException` means you're trying to access an element at a position beyond what the array is holding, hence out of bounds. If you want it to throw an OutOfBoundsException when you have an array that is *too big* (which is not what the exception was really made for), you have to `throw` it on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you are expecting an exception (`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`) to the thrown at line
`name = rawData.trim().split("[\\s,]+");`
with an argument that the size of array (`name`) is fixed to 3, and when if the input is beyond 3 then the exception must be thrown; which is not the case.

The reason is in the way assignment happens in java. When you declare `String[] name = new String[3];`, then an object is created in java heap and its reference is assigned to variable `name` which is in stack memory.
And when this line `name = rawData.trim().split("[\\s,]+");` gets executed then a new array object is created in heap and the variable `name` starts pointing to the newly created array object on heap. Note: the old object will get available for garbage collection after some time.
This eventually changes the length of the array variable (`name`) and you do not get any ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

You can understand this more clearly by printing the object on console, like `System.out.println(name);` after its initialisation and post its assignment.

I will also suggest you to refer this link (https://books.trinket.io/thinkjava2/chapter7.html#elements) to understand how array are created, initialised and copied etc..

Code with system.out commands (for understanding)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReturnArrayExample1 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] a = names(scnr);
        System.out.println("Variable (a) is referring to > " + a);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println(a[i] + " in index[" + i + "].");
        }
        scnr.close();
    }

    public static String[] names(Scanner scnr) {
        String[] name = new String[3]; // initializing
        System.out.println("Variable (name) is referring to > " + name);
        boolean run = true;
        do {
            try {
                System.out.println("Enter 3 names separated by commas ',':(Example: keith, mark, mike)");
                String rawData = scnr.nextLine();
                if (rawData.isEmpty()) {
                    System.err.println("Nothing was entered!");
                    throw new Exception();
                } else {
                    name = rawData.trim().split("[\\s,]+");
                    System.out.println("Now Variable (name) is referring to > " + name);
                    run = false;
                }
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                System.err.println("Input is out of bounds!\nUnsuccessful!");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Invalid entry!\nUnsuccessful!");
            }
        } while (run == true);

        System.out.println("Successful!");
        scnr.close();
        return name;
    }
}
```

I you want to throw exception when input is more than 3 then there are many ways to do it. One suggestion from @mohamedmoselhy.com is also decent.

Answer (score 0):

If you want java to throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException you have to preserve the created `names` instance and let java copy the array into your names array:

```
    String[] names=new String[3];
    String[] rawElements=rawData.trim().split("[\\s,]+");
    System.arraycopy(rawElements, 0, names, 0, rawElements.length);
```

output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at stackoverflow.OutOfBound.main(OutOfBound.java:8)
```